How to update the button label of a fileInput after a button click?
Is there a way to update the button label of a fileInput button after the button was clicked and the triggered event has finished? I have my fileInput call customized to hide the progress bar and the text field. I'm also disabling the button once done. I want the "Get File" label of the button to change to something like for example "Done". I've found ways to use runjs() to change the entire button class,  but I'm unsure how to specifically call the button label? Bonus points if I could also add an icon to my updated label.
All of this is easily achieved with a combination of an actionButton and file.choose(), but that doesn't work on shinyapps.io, so I need a workaround.
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

#custom function to hide the text field next to the button
fileInput2 <- function(..., label="") {
  temp <- fileInput(..., label=label)
  # Cut away the label
  temp$children[[1]] <- NULL
  # Cut away the input field (after label is cut, this is position 1 now)
  temp$children[[1]]$children[[2]] <- NULL
  # Remove input group classes (makes button flat on one side)
  temp$children[[1]]$attribs$class <- NULL
  temp$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$attribs$class <- NULL
  temp
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}")),
  fileInput2("file", label=NULL, buttonLabel="Get File", placeholder=NULL, width='175px'),
 
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  observeEvent(input$file,{

    #...loading the data and doing something with it...

    shinyjs::disable("file") #disable the button
    runjs('$("#file").parents("span").addClass("disabled")') #make it look disabled
    #runjs("$('#file') ... now also update the button label...")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)


Using shinyjs, you could e.g. include the following at a suitable position:
runjs(
      "
      var button = $('#file').closest('.btn-file')[0]
      button.childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'Done';
      "
)

This would change the label of your input with id = "file" from "Get File" to "Done" as requested.
If you want to add an icon in the updated text, you have to edit the innerHTML (add an i tag). Here is an example how the js could look like for a file icon from Font Awesome (shiny::icon(folder)).
var myFileInputButton = $('#file').closest('.btn-file')[0]

var i = document.createElement("i");
i.className = "fa-solid fa-file"; 

myFileInputButton.append(i); # use prepend() if it shall occur at the beginning

It would look like this:

Notice that depending on which icon from which library you want to use, you may have to add some more code.

Thank you. I'm not sure I understand where I have to add the second part for the icon and where the myFileInputButton name is coming from. If I wanted to combine the two, i.e. updating the label AND adding an icon, do I need to do this in two runjs() calls as outlined above or can I somehow combine it into one? I'm not very experienced with JS.

Yes, you can write it inside one runjs(), I just encapsulated it for the answer. In that case you e.g. could drop the var myFileInputButton line and use in the last line with append the variable from above, e.g. button. Is this understandable?

Yes, thank you so much, this makes a lot of sense. In addition to append and prepend, is there an argument to also remove an existing icon? Setting i.className to Null didn't work.

I think I've figured out how to remove an icon that was added with append, please correct me if this is incorrect and I'm missing something substantial, but it seems to be working on my end: runjs("var button = $('#file').closest('.btn-file'); button.children().last().remove()");

Yes, this is correct if the icon was appended and is therefore the last child.

How would I index the child/icon if it was prepended instead?

Use .first() instead of .last().

You may do this using Javascript :
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}")),
  fileInput("file", label=NULL, buttonLabel="Get File", placeholder=NULL, width='175px'),
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$file,{
    # disable the button
    shinyjs::disable("file") 
    # make it look disabled
    runjs('$("#file").parents("span").addClass("disabled")') 
    # change text
    runjs("var button = document.querySelector('.btn-file');button.textContent = 'Done';")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)



This is great, thank you! Is there any way to include an icon when updating the label? In the ui I can add it like this fileInput("file", label=NULL, buttonLabel=list(icon("folder"),'Get File')) but list(icon("check"),"Done") wasn't working in the runjs call.

The approach given in this answer should not be used since it removes all of the node's children, e.g. described here.
