Why is shinyjs::enable not working for my fileInput?
In my shiny app, I have the fileInput disabled after the data was loaded. I also have a conditional reset button, that lets the user start over from scratch. However, while shinyjs::disable() is working great for my fileInput, shinyjs::enable() is being ignored and the input is not reactivated after being reset. Am I missing something? Is there a different way to re-enable the input? It's also not resetting the look from 'disabled' to 'enabled' despite removing the class.
Is it because I'm running multiple consecutive js on the same input? Can I combine them into one runjs()? I'm not very familiar with JS.
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-file-input-progress {display: none}")),
  fileInput("file", label=NULL, buttonLabel="Get File", placeholder=NULL),
  uiOutput('reset')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  dataloaded<-reactiveVal()
  
  observeEvent(input$file,{
    
    #...loading the data and doing something with it...
    
    shinyjs::disable("file") #disable the button
    runjs('$("#file").parents("span").addClass("disabled")') #make it look disabled
    runjs("var button = document.querySelector('.btn-file');button.textContent = 'Done';")  #change the label
    dataloaded(T)
  })
  
  output$reset <- renderUI({
    req(dataloaded())
    actionButton("reset", "Reset")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    dataloaded(NULL)
    shinyjs::enable("file") 
    runjs("var button = document.querySelector('.btn-file');button.textContent = 'Get File';")
    runjs('$("#file").parents("span").removeClass("disabled")')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)


The problem is that inside the observeEvent for input$file you are doing this:
var button = document.querySelector('.btn-file');

button.textContent = 'Done'; #change the label

However, notice what is written at MDN:

Warning: Setting textContent on a node removes all of the node's
children and replaces them with a single text node with the given
string value.

So you are in particular removing file and later shinyjs::enable("file") can't find it.
Instead as above, do it like this:
var button = document.querySelector('.btn-file');

button.childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'Done';


This works perfectly and makes a lot of sense, thank you! Is there any way to include an icon in the updated text? Normally in the ui I would do it with list(icon('icon'),'Label') but that doesn't work for runjs()

Sure, but this is off-topic here since it has nothing to do with the original question. If your problem is solved, you can accept the answer and ask a new question for this. This is also more helpful for future readers in order to find the suitable content.

I already asked about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78271305/update-the-button-label-of-a-shiny-fileinput-after-click

Also related to changing the label of the button, is there a way to address only a specific fileInput if I have multiple?

Yes, say you have a second input with id file2 and you only want to alter this one, then you could do $('#file2').closest('.btn-file')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = 'Done'. (Outgoing from the id you take the "parent")

Perfect, thank you! Maybe you can add this to your answer in case others have the same question?
